# How to stop D/AudioTrack that working all the time

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, audio

What is the reason for following logger lines

The App don't play video or audio at this time,
it's starting at the immediately after execute Run command on Android Studio and display on Run tab

```
D/AudioTrack( 7824): [audioTrackData][fine] 25s(f:25037 m:914 s:1000 k:0) : pid 7824 uid 10657 sessionId 8033 sr 44100 ch 2 fmt 1
D/AudioTrack( 7824): [audioTrackData][mute] 28s(f:0 m:28040 s:0 k:28040) : pid 7824 uid 10657 sessionId 8025 sr 48000 ch 2 fmt 1
D/AudioTrack( 7824): [audioTrackData][fine] 25s(f:25030 m:1003 s:0 k:0) : pid 7824 uid 10657 sessionId 8089 sr 48000 ch 1 fmt 1
```

***Mobile device***

Redmi 10C

MIUI version MIUI Global 14.0.2

***plugins with audio video***

```
  camera: ^0.10.5+2

  video_compress: ^3.1.0

  video_player: ^2.6.1

  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.0
```

***Flutter Doctor***

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555], locale he-IL)
    • Flutter version 3.10.5 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (13 days ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\merid\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-TiramisuPrivacySandbox, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)

[√] VS Code (version 1.78.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\merid\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • 220333QAG (mobile) • fd8dff64 • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)
    • Windows (desktop)  • windows  • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555]
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.134
    • Edge (web)         • edge     • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 114.0.1823.58

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Did you find the issue? I have the same after using the video_player package.

Comment: didn't find, but I think it stopped, maybe after some plugins upgrade